# Done button hides in "more" tab on changing the orientation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have made a tabbar application with 7 tabs. When i start it in portrait mode,on clicking "more" tab it shows edit button and on clicking edit,done button appears .Now when i change the orientation of my device to landscape,done button hides.

Comment: post some code or image for easily understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call this method. this method is executed when rotate to landscape mode....

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

      [Button setHidden:YES];    

}
```